# parse float with two decimals,

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is the input

```
<input type="text" name="price" class="solo-numeros">
```

with this function

```
$(".solo-numeros").blur(function() {
    var numb = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,"")).toFixed(2);
    $(this).val(numb);
});
```

i try to change the result from the input to a float with two decimals

so i try

```
555.61
```

but on blur the value change to

```
55561.00
```

why is that????

Comment: You are removing the decimal separator with .replace...

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're removing non-numeric characters (`\D`), such as a period. So `"55.61"` becomes `"5561"`, which is then made into a two-decimal string-representation of a float, hence `"5561.00"`

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`Number.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).val().replace(/\D/g,"")` this part replaces the decimal point `.` in your number, `555.61`, making it an integer with value `55561`, then `toFixed()` makes it `55561.00`. Workaround could be to use

```
$(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the line where you compute numb with this one:

```
var numb = _toPrecision( parseFloat( $(this).val() ) , 2 );
```

Using this function:

```
var _toPrecision = function( number , precision ){
    var prec = Math.pow( 10 , precision );
    return Math.round( number * prec ) / prec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\D` replaces any non digit character. `.` is not a digit character, hence it's being removed. Use `[^\d\.]` instead, which means "any character that is not a digit, and not the character `.`.

```
var numb = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "")).toFixed(2);
$(this).val(numb);
```

Output:

```
parseFloat(String('123.456').replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "")).toFixed(2);
//123.46
```

Answer (score 0):

You replace all non-digits in the string which will give you "55561" from "555.61" (the period gets replaced by your regex replace call). This in turn is evaluated to 55561.00 by the toFixed() method.

Try parsing an optional period in your regex something like (untested)

```
 var numb=parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\D(\.\D+)?/g,"")).toFixed(2);
```